# Straightforward way to print a numpy array as python hard-code

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

The premises are these: I'm calculating some coefficients coming from a polynomial fitting through `numpy.polynomial.polynomial`.

I'd like to have them printed in python code to be reused in another script, e.g. something like:

```
my_coeff = np.array([0.1,0.2,...,-0.3])
```

Is there a built-in and straightforward function for doing this?

Comment: There's [`np.array_repr(your_array)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_repr.html), that's probably what you want.

Comment: why not save them to a .npy file and load it in the second script?

Comment: @L3viathan, that was exactly what I was looking for, I've just to append some syntax to be python-compatible. Thanks.
@`yan ziselman`, That is another option too, thanks!